# Do action on publish or update?

Tags: posts, updates, publish

Is there a way to only do a section of code on a template if the post has just been published or updated?

What do I need to wrap around that code?

**UPDATE:**

I need to check if any of my custom-post types called "members" have been saved. The template I'm using to display the posts is single-members.php.

If the post has been saved, then on my single-members.php template, I need to call `get_template_part('geocode');` - **but only if the post has been saved**.

**I DON'T WANT THIS TO HAPPEN IN THE ADMIN AREA, THIS NEEDS TO HAPPEN FRONT-END OF THE WEBSITE. OBVIOUSLY THE ONLY THING I WANT TO DO IN THE ADMIN AREA IS TO CLICK PUBLISH/UPDATE.**

Here's what's in the geocode.php file:

```
<?php 

require("database.php");
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("medicom_wp", $con);


    $company = get_field('company_name');
    $address = get_field('address');
    $city = get_field('city');
    $post_code = get_field('post_code');

    $sql = sprintf("select count('x') as cnt from markers where `name` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($company));
    $row_dup = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql,$con));
    if ($row_dup['cnt'] == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`) VALUES ('".$company."', '".$address.", ".$city.", ".$post_code."', '0.0', '0.0', '')");
}
wp_reset_query();


define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
define("KEY", "");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["address"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // Successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
      $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
      $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE markers " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 1000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}


?>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde When a post is published or updated I want it to trigger some code. To be specific when a custom-post (i.e a company profile) is published or updated then it triggers a Google geocode script.

Comment: You'll need to use the action hooks mentioned in the answer below!

Comment: The post will never be saved when the `single-members.php` template is being loaded. Saving only happens in the wp-admin, which doesn't display any of your theme's templates.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you wrap it in post save_post and post_publish hooks?

You have examples here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

How to do it:
Add this to your functions.php file:

```
function my_data_update () {
 $company = get_field('company_name');
 $address = get_field('address');
 $city = get_field('city');
 $post_code = get_field('post_code');
 //etc etc...
}
add_action('publish_post', 'my_data_update');
add_action('save_post', 'my_data_update');
```

Comment: I believe not. Why do you need it called inside of page template?

Comment: `functions.php` is the perfect place for this.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution.

Comment: I have never tried that, but I believe yes, it can, I don't see why not.
=====
I see your update. I believe you can use that, yes, don't see why.

Comment: Can you explain better?
This part: "but it wasn't on the single-members.php template."

Comment: @OriginalEXE The things I want executed are all front-end, not in the admin area. All I want to do is check if a post was saved, if it was then on the front-end I want it to execute a script. All that I've tried so far executes things in the admin area. For instance, I clicked update on a post in the admin area and it tried to load the geocode.php template.

Comment: I understand. Well, that really depends on the script you are trying to run.
Could you post it on pastebin so I can check it out?

Comment: @OriginalEXE Yep, here's whats in geocode.php - http://pastebin.com/MYbwjV0J

Comment: Do you have something written in error log?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had almost the exact same use case:

- On saving a custom post type, check for the existance of some meta data.
- If it exists, geocode it using the Google Geocode API.
- Save the result as a new meta field (this one hidden so the user can't screw it up).
- *Note: What I do with the data on the front end of the site is handled in a template file using javascript and the Google Maps API.*

It looks like you're assembling multiple fields to get the address (I stored it in one) and you're saving the resulting format differently, but hopefully this serves as a good example that you can borrow from. As I always try to do, I used the WordPress API functions for querying and saving to the database. It's mores secure and future-proof.

Just as @OriginalEXE suggests, I used the [`save_post` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). I don't think you need `publish_post`:

> save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.

A few more notes:

- Note the lower priority of the action. I found that leaving it as the default priority left it looking at the previously saved data (which is saved using Advanced Custom Fields which it looks like you're using).
- The geocoding class was not mine and saved me a huge amount of time. I modified what Sergiy published to use the `wp_remote_get()` function that has better server support than either `curl` or `file_get_contents`. It uses the JSON (Google-recommended) request rather than XML.

I put this in a functionality plugin, but it would work the same in `functions.php`:

```
/* function wc_add_latlong()
 * take address from post, geocode it, and save as a custom meta field
 * @parameter $post_id, id of the post being saved, passed by save_post hook
 * @returns nothing
 **************************************/
function wc_add_latlong( $post_id ) {
    // get the address from ACF field
    $address = get_field( 'wc_map_address', $post_id );
    // Check to see if the post type is right, it's not a revision, and there is an address to geocode
    if( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'wc_biz' && !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && $address ) {
        // call the geocoder class below
        $coords = geocoder::getLocation( $address );
        // split latLngObject with a comma and space
        $lat_long_string = $coords['lat'] . ', ' . $coords['lng'];
        // either add that value as a new post meta field OR update the existing one
        add_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_lat_long', $lat_long_string, true ) || update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_lat_long', $lat_long_string );
    }
}
// This runs on the save_post hook
add_action( 'save_post', 'wc_add_latlong', 11 );

// Thank you Sergiy!
// http://erlycoder.com/45/php-server-side-geocoding-with-google-maps-api-v3
// a class to get the lat and long of an address _server-side_
class geocoder{
    // The base URL for a non-sensor json Google Geocode API request
    static private $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=";

    static public function getLocation($address){
        // append URL-friendly address to base URL
        $url = self::$url.urlencode($address);
            // request the Geocode JSON object from Google
        $resp_json = wp_remote_get($url);
            // decode the body of the response
        $resp = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body($resp_json), true );
            // make sure the remove_get was successful and it geocoded the address
        if( !is_wp_error( $resp_json ) && $resp['status']='OK' ) {
                // success! return the lat and long
            return $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
        }else{
                // we failed, return false
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I've commented all the code so you can understand what's going on. You'll have to adapt it from there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've updated my question with the actual script that geocodes the addresses. Is there a way to incorporate that?